# Egress to a different Cloud service within the same Region is Free?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I see on the GCE product page that "Egress to a different Cloud service within the same Region. (FREE)"

Does this mean if I have machines at Softlayer or Rackspace at the same region (Europe specifically) the network communication would be completely free?

Answer (score 1):

"Region" is a term with very specific meaning in Google Compute Engine, and it refers only to networking within Google datacenters that are in close proximity to one another. For example, traffic between europe-west1-b, europe-west1-c and europe-west1-d zones is all considered to be within the europe-west1 region. Any other endpoint outside of Google's datacenters is considered to be Internet traffic, regardless of where that traffic is being routed geographically.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have read that sentence [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). Please, refer to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general) that has the same table with this other sentence:

> Egress to a different **Google** Cloud service within the same region: No
>   charge

I have reported the issue to the team that updates the documentation and this should be fixed soon.

Thanks for your finding.

Comment: This has been fixed and now that sentence look like the other one: _"Egress to a different **Google** Cloud service within the same region"_.
Thanks!